# Capturing the max value in a data flow

Tags: ssis

I'm just getting back into SSIS after several years of not using it. Here is what I need to do.

```
1) Read a value from a table and store into a variable
2) Create a data flow where I retrieve some number of rows 
   having a value greater than the value retrieved in #1.
3) Store the rows retrieved in #2 into another table
4) Determine the maximum value of a particular column from the rows 
   read in from step #2 and update the table referenced in #1.
```

The first three steps are easy, straightforward and working. However, I'm not certain the best way to accomplish #4.

Comment: Hey Randy, your choice of formatting makes me want to change it to a standard numbered list, but I've noticed that someone's already tried to do that and you rolled back their changes. Out of curiosity, why did you think that the suggested change made it worse? Is it something about the monospace font or the grey background that makes your list look pretty in your eyes? Because I'm sure the horizontal scrolling doesn't make it the least bit easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best can always be subjective but the most straight forward mechanism would be to add a Multicast component prior to your destination.

The Multicast will allow all the data flowing through the pipeline to show up in more than one stream. This is all done through pointers to the actual data buffers and doesn't result in physical copies of the data being strewn about.

From the Multicast, connect it to an Aggregate component and perform a MAX operation on whatever column you're using.

You know that you will only have one row coming from this aggregate so I'd use an OLE DB Command component to update your table #1. Something like

```
UPDATE ETLStatus
SET MaxValue = ?
WHERE PackageName = ?;
```

And then you'd map column names in like

```
MaxValue => Parameter_0
PackageName => Parameter_1
```